# Problem with tabIndex

Tags: c#, silverlight

i am with a problem on tab index.

I have made a form and set the tab index, by code to all Control on that form.

Howerver the tabindex is not folowing the correct order.

I already set all the Controls to isTabStop to true. Someone have any kind of ideia why this 
is happend´s?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tab index you assigned to a control is already used on another tab page you can't reuse the tab index. Go reset the tabindex in some way and renumber by hand.

Splitting tab content into different user controls should help.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the answer i have done the tab index, but now i am  with another problem
The Tabnavigation is Following the Grid and not the tab index, example
The when i press tab is done this order 1..20 ,21, 26,22,23,24,25,27 why this is happend?

Comment: Hi, please accept the answer if you think it is good enough for the original question.
The Tab-order follows from group to group and then from control to control. Are those out of order tabindexes inside other controls?